# neovim is transparent but the auto copplete window is pink.how to make it semi transparent (black) too?

Tags: vim-plugin, neovim

i use parrot security as my daily  distro. its mate terminal is transparent so is vim .but i wanted to get auto complete and used some plugins.auto complete window appears to be in pink which looks really ugly in semi transparent black background.i changed the theme and it was fixed but so was gone vim transparency .

> in short word (1)i have to keep the default (2)i have to keep
> transparent vim (3)i have to change the  auto complete window from
> pink to semi transparent black

here  is my init.vimrc

```
set number
set expandtab
set autoindent
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4

"Enable mouse click for nvim
set mouse=a
"Fix cursor replacement after closing nvim
set guicursor=n-v-c-sm:block,

  "Shift + Tab does inverse tab
inoremap <S-Tab> <C-d>

"See invisible characters
set list listchars=tab:>\ ,trail:+,eol:$
let $NVIM_TUI_ENABLE_CURSORE_SHAPE=1
"wrap to next line when end of line is reached
set whichwrap+=<,>,[,]
"-----------------------------------------------------------
"===========================================================
"-----------------------------------------------------------
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plug 'tsony-tsonev/nerdtree-git-plugin'
Plug 'Xuyuanp/nerdtree-git-plugin'
Plug 'tiagofumo/vim-nerdtree-syntax-highlight'
Plug 'ryanoasis/vim-devicons'
Plug 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'
Plug 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim' " fuzzy find files
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdcommenter'
Plug 'christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator'
Plug 'morhetz/gruvbox'
Plug 'HerringtonDarkholme/yats.vim' " TS Syntax
Plug 'joshdick/onedark.vim'
Plug 'sheerun/vim-polyglot'
Plug 'sheerun/vim-polyglot'
    " File Explorer
    Plug 'scrooloose/NERDTree'
    " Auto pairs for '(' '[' '{'
    Plug 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs'
    Plug 'http://github.com/tpope/vim-surround' " Surrounding ysw)
    Plug 'https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree' " NerdTree
    Plug 'https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary' " For Commenting gcc & gc
    Plug 'https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline' " Status bar
    Plug 'https://github.com/lifepillar/pgsql.vim' " PSQL Pluging needs :SQLSetType pgsql.vim
    Plug 'https://github.com/ap/vim-css-color' " CSS Color Preview
    Plug 'https://github.com/rafi/awesome-vim-colorschemes' " Retro Scheme
    Plug 'https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim'  " Auto Completion
    Plug 'https://github.com/ryanoasis/vim-devicons' " Developer Icons
    Plug 'https://github.com/tc50cal/vim-terminal' " Vim Terminal
    Plug 'https://github.com/preservim/tagbar' " Tagbar for code navigation
    Plug 'https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors' " CTRL + N for multiple cursors


call plug#end()

inoremap jk <ESC>
nmap <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
vmap ++ <plug>NERDCommenterToggle
nmap ++ <plug>NERDCommenterToggle

" open NERDTree automatically
"autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1
"autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree

let g:NERDTreeGitStatusWithFlags = 1
"let g:WebDevIconsUnicodeDecorateFolderNodes = 1
"let g:NERDTreeGitStatusNodeColorization = 1
"let g:NERDTreeColorMapCustom = {
    "\ "Staged"    : "#0ee375",  
    "\ "Modified"  : "#d9bf91",  
    "\ "Renamed"   : "#51C9FC",  
    "\ "Untracked" : "#FCE77C",  
    "\ "Unmerged"  : "#FC51E6",  
    "\ "Dirty"     : "#FFBD61",  
    "\ "Clean"     : "#87939A",   
    "\ "Ignored"   : "#808080"   
    "\ }                         


let g:NERDTreeIgnore = ['^node_modules$']

" vim-prettier
"let g:prettier#quickfix_enabled = 0
"let g:prettier#quickfix_auto_focus = 0
" prettier command for coc
command! -nargs=0 Prettier :CocCommand prettier.formatFile
" run prettier on save
"let g:prettier#autoformat = 0
"autocmd BufWritePre *.js,*.jsx,*.mjs,*.ts,*.tsx,*.css,*.less,*.scss,*.json,*.graphql,*.md,*.vue,*.yaml,*.html PrettierAsync


" ctrlp
let g:ctrlp_user_command = ['.git/', 'git --git-dir=%s/.git ls-files -oc --exclude-standard']

" j/k will move virtual lines (lines that wrap)
noremap <silent> <expr> j (v:count == 0 ? 'gj' : 'j')
noremap <silent> <expr> k (v:count == 0 ? 'gk' : 'k')

set relativenumber

set smarttab
set cindent
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
" always uses spaces instead of tab characters
set expandtab



" sync open file with NERDTree
" " Check if NERDTree is open or active
function! IsNERDTreeOpen()        
  return exists("t:NERDTreeBufName") && (bufwinnr(t:NERDTreeBufName) != -1)
endfunction

" Call NERDTreeFind iff NERDTree is active, current window contains a modifiable
" file, and we're not in vimdiff
function! SyncTree()
  if &modifiable && IsNERDTreeOpen() && strlen(expand('%')) > 0 && !&diff
    NERDTreeFind
    wincmd p
  endif
endfunction

" Highlight currently open buffer in NERDTree
autocmd BufEnter * call SyncTree()

" coc config
let g:coc_global_extensions = [
  \ 'coc-snippets',
  \ 'coc-pairs',
  \ 'coc-tsserver',
  \ 'coc-eslint', 
  \ 'coc-prettier', 
  \ 'coc-json', 
  \ ]
" from readme
" if hidden is not set, TextEdit might fail.
set hidden " Some servers have issues with backup files, see #649 set nobackup set nowritebackup " Better display for messages set cmdheight=2 " You will have bad experience for diagnostic messages when it's default 4000.


" don't give |ins-completion-menu| messages.
set shortmess+=c
" always show signcolumns
set signcolumn=yes

" Use tab for trigger completion with characters ahead and navigate.
" Use command ':verbose imap <tab>' to make sure tab is not mapped by other plugin.
inoremap <silent><expr> <TAB>
      \ pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" :
      \ <SID>check_back_space() ? "\<TAB>" :
      \ coc#refresh()
inoremap <expr><S-TAB> pumvisible() ? "\<C-p>" : "\<C-h>"

function! s:check_back_space() abort
  let col = col('.') - 1
  return !col || getline('.')[col - 1]  =~# '\s'
endfunction

" Use <c-space> to trigger completion.
inoremap <silent><expr> <c-space> coc#refresh()

" Use <cr> to confirm completion, `<C-g>u` means break undo chain at current position.
" Coc only does snippet and additional edit on confirm.
inoremap <expr> <cr> pumvisible() ? "\<C-y>" : "\<C-g>u\<CR>"
" Or use `complete_info` if your vim support it, like:
" inoremap <expr> <cr> complete_info()["selected"] != "-1" ? "\<C-y>" : "\<C-g>u\<CR>"

" Use `[g` and `]g` to navigate diagnostics
nmap <silent> [g <Plug>(coc-diagnostic-prev)
nmap <silent> ]g <Plug>(coc-diagnostic-next)

" Remap keys for gotos
nmap <silent> gd <Plug>(coc-definition)
nmap <silent> gy <Plug>(coc-type-definition)
nmap <silent> gi <Plug>(coc-implementation)
nmap <silent> gr <Plug>(coc-references)

" Use K to show documentation in preview window
nnoremap <silent> K :call <SID>show_documentation()<CR>

function! s:show_documentation()
  if (index(['vim','help'], &filetype) >= 0)
    execute 'h '.expand('<cword>')
  else
    call CocAction('doHover')
  endif
endfunction

" Highlight symbol under cursor on CursorHold
autocmd CursorHold * silent call CocActionAsync('highlight')

" Remap for rename current word
nmap <F2> <Plug>(coc-rename)

" Remap for format selected region
xmap <leader>f  <Plug>(coc-format-selected)
nmap <leader>f  <Plug>(coc-format-selected)

augroup mygroup
  autocmd!
  " Setup formatexpr specified filetype(s).
  autocmd FileType typescript,json setl formatexpr=CocAction('formatSelected')
  " Update signature help on jump placeholder
  autocmd User CocJumpPlaceholder call CocActionAsync('showSignatureHelp')
augroup end

" Remap for do codeAction of selected region, ex: `<leader>aap` for current paragraph
xmap <leader>a  <Plug>(coc-codeaction-selected)
nmap <leader>a  <Plug>(coc-codeaction-selected)

" Remap for do codeAction of current line
nmap <leader>ac  <Plug>(coc-codeaction)
" Fix autofix problem of current line
nmap <leader>qf  <Plug>(coc-fix-current)

" Create mappings for function text object, requires document symbols feature of languageserver.
xmap if <Plug>(coc-funcobj-i)
xmap af <Plug>(coc-funcobj-a)
omap if <Plug>(coc-funcobj-i)
omap af <Plug>(coc-funcobj-a)

" Use <C-d> for select selections ranges, needs server support, like: coc-tsserver, coc-python
nmap <silent> <C-d> <Plug>(coc-range-select)
xmap <silent> <C-d> <Plug>(coc-range-select)

" Use `:Format` to format current buffer
command! -nargs=0 Format :call CocAction('format')

" Use `:Fold` to fold current buffer
command! -nargs=? Fold :call     CocAction('fold', <f-args>)

" use `:OR` for organize import of current buffer
command! -nargs=0 OR   :call     CocAction('runCommand', 'editor.action.organizeImport')

" Add status line support, for integration with other plugin, checkout `:h coc-status`
set statusline^=%{coc#status()}%{get(b:,'coc_current_function','')}

" Using CocList
" Show all diagnostics
nnoremap <silent> <space>a  :<C-u>CocList diagnostics<cr>
" Manage extensions
nnoremap <silent> <space>e  :<C-u>CocList extensions<cr>
" Show commands
nnoremap <silent> <space>c  :<C-u>CocList commands<cr>
" Find symbol of current document
nnoremap <silent> <space>o  :<C-u>CocList outline<cr>
" Search workspace symbols
nnoremap <silent> <space>s  :<C-u>CocList -I symbols<cr>
" Do default action for next item.
nnoremap <silent> <space>j  :<C-u>CocNext<CR>
" Do default action for previous item.
nnoremap <silent> <space>k  :<C-u>CocPrev<CR>
" Resume latest coc list
nnoremap <silent> <space>p  :<C-u>CocListResume<CR>
if (has("termguicolors"))
    set termguicolors
  endif


"onedark theme"
syntax on
```

so what should i so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using neovim there is an option called [`:h pumblend`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/options.html#%27pumblend%27) which can be used to change the transparency of the popup menu.

Are you sure `gruvbox` caused your vim to lose transparency? I am not sure if vim is able to change a terminal emulator's transparency. I or someone else might be able to advise you better if you post pictures of what has changed.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12664/is-there-any-way-to-change-the-popup-menu-color

Comment: set vim transparent background with 
:hi normal guibg=NONE ctermbg=NONE